# Android device-owner Error: Unknown admin: ComponentInfo

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, device-owner, dpm

When I run adb shell dpm-set-device-owner com.example.park_app/com.example.park_app.MyAdmin, it returns Error: Unknown admin: ComponentInfo{com.example.park_app/com.example.park_app.MyAdmin.java}
[image]

```
D:\workspace\Taichung Park\Park_App>adb shell dpm set-device-owner 
com.example.park_app/com.example.park_app.MyAdmin.java
usage: dpm [subcommand] [options]
usage: dpm set-active-admin [ --user <USER_ID> | current ] <COMPONENT>
usage: dpm set-device-owner [ --user <USER_ID> | current *EXPERIMENTAL* ] [ --name <NAME> ] <COMPONENT>
usage: dpm set-profile-owner [ --user <USER_ID> | current ] [ --name <NAME> ] <COMPONENT>
usage: dpm remove-active-admin [ --user <USER_ID> | current ] [ --name <NAME> ] <COMPONENT>

dpm set-active-admin: Sets the given component as active admin for an existing user.

dpm set-device-owner: Sets the given component as active admin, and its package as device owner.

dpm set-profile-owner: Sets the given component as active admin and profile owner for an existing user.

dpm remove-active-admin: Disables an active admin, the admin must have declared android:testOnly in the application in its manifest. This will also remove device and profile owners.

dpm clear-freeze-period-record: clears framework-maintained record of past freeze periods that the device went through. For use during feature development to prevent triggering restriction on setting freeze periods.

dpm force-security-logs: makes all security logs available to the DPC and triggers DeviceAdminReceiver.onSecurityLogsAvailable() if needed.

Error: Unknown admin: 
ComponentInfo{com.example.park_app/com.example.park_app.MyAdmin.java}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.park_app.MyAdmin"
    android:label="ParkAppAdmin"
    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.device_admin"
        android:resource="@xml/device_admin" />
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

MyAdmin.java:

```
public class MyAdmin extends DeviceAdminReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onProfileProvisioningComplete(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
        DevicePolicyManager devicePolicyManager =
            (DevicePolicyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DEVICE_POLICY_SERVICE);
        ComponentName componentName = getComponentName(context);
        devicePolicyManager.setProfileName(componentName, "KioskMode");
        Intent launch = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        launch.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(launch);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEnabled(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("onEnabled");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDisabled(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull Intent intent) {
        System.out.println("onDisabled");
    }

    private ComponentName getComponentName(Context context){
        return new ComponentName(context.getApplicationContext(), MyAdmin.class);
    }
}
```

How can I fix the issue to make application a device owner